# URL should not contain Servlet name after exporting

Tags: java, html, servlets, apache-poi

```
public class ExcelWriter extends HttpServlet{
    private void writeExcel(List<Book> listBook, String excelFilePath)
            throws IOException {
        Workbook workbook = getWorkbook(excelFilePath);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

        int rowCount = 0;

        for (Book aBook : listBook) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
            writeBook(aBook, row);
        }

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                excelFilePath))) {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
        }
    }

    private void writeBook(Book aBook, Row row) {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue(aBook.getTitle());

        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue(aBook.getAuthor());

        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue(aBook.getPrice());
    }

    private List<Book> getListBook() {
        Book book1 = new Book("Head  Java", "Anot Serria", 79);
        Book book2 = new Book("Effective Java 1", "Bnot Bloch", 36);
        Book book3 = new Book("Clean Code 1", "Cnot Martin", 42);
        Book book4 = new Book("Thinking in Java 2", "D Eckel", 35);

        List<Book> listBook = Arrays.asList(book1, book2, book3, book4);

        return listBook;
    }

    private Workbook getWorkbook(String excelFilePath) throws IOException {
        Workbook workbook = null;

        if (excelFilePath.endsWith("xlsx")) {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        } else if (excelFilePath.endsWith("xls")) {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The specified file is not Excel file");
        }

        return workbook;

    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            ExcelWriter excelWriter = new ExcelWriter();
            List<Book> listBook = excelWriter.getListBook();
            String excelFilePath = "C:\\ExcelTemp\\Temp.xls";
             excelWriter.writeExcel(listBook, excelFilePath);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

- After the excel file gets downloaded the Servlet should point me to the initial view page i.e From where I export the data. I don't want to forward it to the same page being used.

  The functionality should be like I export the data from index.`html-->ExcelWriter Servlet`. But the url shouldn't should show the Servlet part.           Please help me with it. I am using Apache POI and Servlet. I also have a POJO name book with getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do servlet mapping in web descriptor file (xml file).

Comment: Servlet mapping is done by me, i want the same index.html after exporting. It should not go to the SERVLET NAME in url

Comment: Make an AJAX call in that case. It will be an asynchronous call so url will not be altered.